# Elastic Search: limit values to a list of enums

Tags: elasticsearch

Looking for a way to limit a field in the index mapping of the ElasticSearch to a list of known words.

```
/myIndex
{ "mapping": {
  "demo1": { 
    "type": "keyword", 
    "allowed_values": [ "a", "b", "c" ] 
   }
}
```

Seems like there is no `type: enum` field available. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search is schema-less. It allows any number of fields and any content in fields without any logical constraints.

In a distributed system integrity checking can be expensive so checks like RDBMS are not available in elastic search.

Best way is to do validations at client side.

Another approach is to use [ingest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html)

> Ingest pipelines let you perform common transformations on your data before indexing. For example, you can use pipelines to remove fields, extract values from text, and enrich your data.

```
For testing
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "if (ctx.demo1 !='a' && ctx.demo1 !='b' && ctx.demo1 !='c') { throw new Exception('Add valid values') }"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_id": "1",
      "_source": {
        "demo1": "a"
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_id": "2",
      "_source": {
        "demo1": "d"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Ingest pipeline

PUT _ingest/pipeline/check-value_pipeline
{
  "description": "Check if demo field has valid values",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "if (ctx.demo1 !='a' && ctx.demo1 !='b' && ctx.demo1 !='c') { throw new Exception('Add valid values') }"
      }
    }
  ]
}

This will throw error
POST index115/_doc?pipeline=check-value_pipeline
{
  "demo1":"d"
}
```